# JIRA- How to immigrate data from an issue to another?

Tags: jira, workflow, issue-tracking

Currently I am working on a Jira project and in that project I have built a workflow. The workflow runs with a single issue and runs successfully.

This workflow mainly consists of 2 parts. In the 1st part, the authorizations are set and approved. In the 2nd part some assignments are being conducted according to the authorizations that have been set in the first part.

This workflow works well but I have been asked to implement this project with 2 different workflows which will be run by 2 different issues.

So my question is, how can I migrate data from the first issue to the second issue? Somehow I need to transfer the authorization info to the second issue so that the second workflow will be able to run.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand correctly or not. Are you looking to migrate your workflow to the new project?! If so - you can export the workflow and restore it in new project :-)

Comment: @SalehParsa Nope Dude, I want to split the workflow into 2 different workflows. However, in first workflow the authorization information is set. Second workflow needs to get this authorization info in order to run. Normally in combined version the workflow works well but I am asked to split it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A late respond: I achieved this by using the sub-task mechanism. I also used post-functions in the workflow which made me able to get the authorization data from the first issue.

Answer (score 0):

Once the authorization is complete you could change the issue type to a type which uses the second workflow. If you want to retain the authorization record, you could clone the first issue and then change the issue type of the clone.